# Change load more button value according to the condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

Hi I am using **load more button** to load content of the next page on the same web page. It can display unlimited no of results on the same page. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name, message FROM paginate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page);
    $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
    $results->bind_result($id, $name, $message);

    while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
        echo '<li>'.$id.') <strong>'.$name.'</strong> : '.$message.'</li>';
    }
    <ul id="results"></ul>
    <div align="center">
    <button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  class="animation_image" style="float:left;"> Load More</button> <!-- load button -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery
    
        var track_page = 1;

```
    $("#load_more_button").click(function (e) {
        track_page++;
        load_contents(track_page);
    });

    function load_contents(track_page){
        $('.animation_image').show();       
        $.post( 'fetch_pages.php', {'page': track_page}, function(data){
           if(data.trim().length == 0){
                $("#load_more_button").text("No more records!").prop("disabled", true);
            }

            $("#results").append(data);

            $('.animation_image').hide();
        });
    }
</script>
```

fetch_pages.php

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name, message FROM paginate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$results->bind_param("dd", $position, $item_per_page);
$results->execute();
$results->bind_result($id, $name, $message);


while($results->fetch()){
    echo '<li>'.$id.') <strong>'.$name.'</strong> : '.$message.'</li>';
}
```

What i want to do is to change Load More button value accordingly ?

1. If there are no results then display **NO RESULTS !** in load more button.
2. If there are less than 6 results then first display **LOADING DATA** in load more button until the data loads and then display **END OF RESULTS !** in load more button.
3. AND if there are more then 5 results then first display **LOADING DATA** and then display **LOAD MORE** after that.

Here is what i have tried so far and as a result it becomes more confusing for visitors as it display **END OF RESULTS!** until data loads.

```
    <?php
        if((results)<5){
    ?>
            <div align="center" class="load-more-b">
                <button id="load_more_button">END OF RESULTS !</button>
            </div>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
            <div align="center" class="load-more-b">
                <button id="load_more_button"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"  class="animation_image" style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;LOAD MORE</button> 
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I know i need to make changes in jquery code to achieve this, but i don't have enough knowledge about jquery. So please Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Now i am displaying my first page without AJAX call and to display second page and so on i am using AJAX call. Now the problem is, If there are more than 5 results, It displays LOAD MORE button with GIF image. But i want only LOAD MORE button without GIF And when user click on that button then GIF image to be displayed until the next results load. Thanks...
Its working very well for me. But my problem is when i use this script it takes 2-3 seconds to load data. And during these 2-3 seconds **Load More** displays on the screen.

Comment: let me get it straight you want the button to each time load 5 more until their is no more results then the button should say no more results? so if the first result is 5 then if button is clicked once there are 10 results?

Comment: @Gert Yes I want this....But i have found a way to do this in another way which is more comfortable for me... And i have a little issue over that...Let me edit my code. Thanks

Comment: you should use sessions for this , edit your code and let me see

Comment: for starters you should count the results $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($results);

Comment: create 2 sessions 1 for button status and 1 for how many results, at first set the status of the button to load more in a php variable, then each time it is click the result session is +5 results and use that in you query for limit of of results, each time it exucutes you check if the row count is smaller then num_rows and change button in session accordingly, the other option is to load all the results and hide 5 less each time in javascript

Comment: @Gert I have Solved by my own by just giving a css property to animation_image {display:none}....Thanks for your time...